# child thread IO error when using bluetooth in java(on android studio)

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth

I'd like to create a child thread to create a bluetooth socket.
so I create a child thread in main thread.like this.

```
 serverThread myThread = new serverThread();
 myThread.passValue((int)id);
 myThread.start();
```

my code in child thread:

```
   private class serverThread extends Thread
    {
        private BluetoothSocket bt_socket; 
        private BluetoothServerSocket bt_server;
        public int device_id;
        public  UUID uuid;
        public void passValue(int id)
        {
            this.device_id = id;
        }
        @Override
         public void run()
        {
            this.uuid = UUID.fromString("00001001-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

            try {

                System.out.println(bt_device.get((int) this.device_id).getName());
                bt_server = bluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(bt_device.get((int) this.device_id).getName(), uuid);
                bt_socket = bt_device.get((int) this.device_id).createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
                System.out.println(bt_server.toString());
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("error to get blue_server&socket");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //
            try {
                bt_server.accept();
                System.out.println("thread has accept the connection");
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            OutputStream output = null;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int size = 20000;
            try {
                while (size != 0) {
                    size--;
                    output = bt_socket.getOutputStream();
                    if (output != null) {
                        String tex = "x: "+size;//sensorvalue[0].toString();
                        output.write(tex.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                       // debugView.setText("sending:\n" + tex);
                        try{
                            Thread.sleep(1);
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                try {
                    bt_socket.close();
                    bt_server.close();
                }
                catch (IOException a)
                {
                    a.printStackTrace();
                }
                debugView.setText("error:\n");
            }
            //close if finished
            try {
                bt_socket.close();
                bt_server.close();
            }
            catch (IOException a)
            {
                a.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

when it comes to:

```
   try {
                while (size != 0) {
                    size--;
                    output = bt_socket.getOutputStream();
                    if (output != null) {
                        String tex = "x: "+size;//sensorvalue[0].toString();
                        output.write(tex.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                       // debugView.setText("sending:\n" + tex);
                        try{
                            Thread.sleep(1);
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

```
it's error msg:
10-23 22:23:15.698 13027-13593/com.example.administrator.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11975
                                                                                         Process: com.example.administrator.myapplication, PID: 13027
                                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.OutputStream.write(byte[], int, int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                             at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.write(BluetoothSocket.java:564)
                                                                                             at android.bluetooth.BluetoothOutputStream.write(BluetoothOutputStream.java:85)
                                                                                             at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:82)
                                                                                             at com.example.administrator.myapplication.MainActivity$serverThread.run(MainActivity.java:310)
```

I created a child thread to create and transmit Bluetooth socket. But it seems that the output cache of the socket is null on the socket's read-write display, but the server-side accept function is fine.

why program crash seems like the child thread cannot write data into output streambuffer?

### and how to solve this problem?

I tried bt_socket.connect(),
new problem:

```
10-24 13:15:15.217 13814-14553/com.example.administrator.myapplication W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
10-24 13:15:15.247 13814-14553/com.example.administrator.myapplication W/System.err: java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
10-24 13:15:15.257 13814-14553/com.example.administrator.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:700)
10-24 13:15:15.257 13814-14553/com.example.administrator.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readInt(BluetoothSocket.java:712)
10-24 13:15:15.257 13814-14553/com.example.administrator.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:381)
10-24 13:15:15.257 13814-14553/com.example.administrator.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.example.administrator.myapplication.MainActivity$serverThread.run(MainActivity.java:304)
10-24 13:15:15.257 13814-14553/com.example.administrator.myapplication I/System.out: reached
10-24 13:15:15.267 13814-14553/com.example.administrator.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-14107
                                                                                         Process: com.example.administrator.myapplication, PID: 13814
                                                                                         android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6806)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:974)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:5100)
                                                                                             at android.view.View.invalidateInternal(View.java:12817)
                                                                                             at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:12781)
                                                                                             at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:12765)
                                                                                             at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:7370)
                                                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4426)
                                                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4283)
                                                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4258)
                                                                                             at com.example.administrator.myapplication.MainActivity$serverThread.run(MainActivity.java:348)
```

Comment: By the way, when I execute the program on the main thread, everything is fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluetooth Socket OutputStream NullPointerException when calling Write()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42981325/bluetooth-socket-outputstream-nullpointerexception-when-calling-write)

Comment: tks.I tried bt_socket.connect(),which leads to a new error.

Comment: I figure out that I used a view hierarchy,so,I delete debugView.setText("error:\n"); but  it still tells that socket is closed. debug info tells "java.io.IOException: socket not created"

Comment: The problem is that I wrote the program directly on the main thread, and it turned out to be all right. A socket creation failure occurs when you place it in a child thread.When a child thread executes, the socket cannot open the input and output streams, and there is no way to use socket methods, such as the first error.

Comment: finally I solved my problem！when creating socket using accept() instead of bt_device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);will solve the problem,thks bro!